# How to align HBox by using BorderPane alignment in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

What am i trying is to align HBox Buttons to center in the Bottom in dialog box.
I want to do this in fxml.However,BorderPane alignment is working in label.
Here is code from my side.I think BorderPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" must work even if the tag is Bottom.

Class file:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HBoxDialog extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HBoxDialog.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

<top>
    <Label text="this is dialogbox" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER"/>
    <font>
        <Font size="35"/>
    </font>
</top>

<bottom>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Button text="Okay" prefWidth="90" BorderPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER"/>
        <Button text="Cancel" prefWidth="90" BorderPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER"/>
        <Button text="Help" prefWidth="90" BorderPane.alignment="BASELINE_RIGHT"/>
    </HBox>
</bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: The border pane alignment properties only make sense if they are set on nodes whose parent is a `BorderPane`. The parent of the `Button`s is a `HBox`, so these will be ignored. If you want the buttons centered, just set `alignment="CENTER"` (not `BorderPane.alignment`) on the `HBox`

Comment: @James_D Thanks!It worked but how?As far as i know the alignment priority is given to BorderPane alignment element.So, i tried to set the Label alignment to center by using alignment="CENTER" in top element and it didn't worked but now it is working in HBox even if the element is bottom only.Please clear my doubts.

Comment: Moved comments to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BorderPane.alignment` static property only makes sense for nodes whose parent is a `BorderPane`. The `Button`s defined in your FXML file have an `HBox` as a parent, so setting the `BorderPane.alignment` property on the buttons will have no effect.

You can achieve the desired effect by centering the buttons within the `HBox`, simply by using the `alignment` property of the `HBox` (which positions the `HBox`'s child nodes within its bounds):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <top>
        <Label text="this is dialogbox"
            BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" />
        <font>
            <Font size="35" />
        </font>
    </top>

    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
            <Button text="Okay" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Cancel" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Help" prefWidth="90" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

This gives

[image]

The reason that the `Label` needs `BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"` but the `HBox` needs `alignment="CENTER"` is because they have different *resizable ranges*, and in particular their max widths are different. The max width of a label, by default, is its preferred width, whereas the max width of an `HBox` is infinite. You can see this by setting background colors on them both:

```xml
    <Label text="this is dialogbox"
        BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" 
        style="-fx-background-color: aquamarine;"/>

    <!-- ... -->

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER"
      style="-fx-background-color: lightskyblue;">
```

[image]

The `alignment` property positions the content of a node within its bounds. Since the label has no extra space within its bounds for the text to be positioned, with the default settings the `alignment` property will have no effect. On the other hand, the label is less wide than the top region of the border pane, so there is room to position it within that region. The `BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"` attribute centers the entire label within the top region of the border pane.

By contrast, the `HBox` itself already fills the entire width of the bottom region of the border pane. So there is no additional space to align it within that region, and so for the `HBox`, setting `BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"` will have no effect. On the other hand, there is more space in the `HBox` itself than is needed for the buttons, so the buttons (the content of the `HBox`) can be aligned within the `HBox` itself using the `alignment="CENTER"` property of the `HBox`.

If you want, you can change the max widths to achieve the same effect. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.Double?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <top>
        <Label text="this is dialogbox"
            alignment="CENTER" 
            style="-fx-background-color: aquamarine;">

            <maxWidth>
             <Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE"/>
            </maxWidth>

        </Label>
        <font>
            <Font size="35" />
        </font>
    </top>

    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER"
          style="-fx-background-color: lightskyblue;">
            <Button text="Okay" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Cancel" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Help" prefWidth="90" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

allows the label to grow (like the default for the `HBox`), so now its `alignment` property has the desired effect:

[image]

or

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <top>
        <Label text="this is dialogbox"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" 
            style="-fx-background-color: aquamarine;" />
        <font>
            <Font size="35" />
        </font>
    </top>

    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="10" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"
          style="-fx-background-color: lightskyblue;">

          <maxWidth>
              <Region fx:constant="USE_PREF_SIZE" />
          </maxWidth>

            <Button text="Okay" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Cancel" prefWidth="90" />
            <Button text="Help" prefWidth="90" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

makes the `HBox` behave like the button, so now its `BorderPane.alignment` gives the desired effect:

[image]